# ELANTech Touchpad no cursor movement/right-click after upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10 (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, 14.10, touchpad, asus, elantech

I upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 on my ASUS UX305F and the cursor on my touchpad no longer moves and only the left-click functionality works.

It's still recognized:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

And it's enabled:

```
$ xinput list-props 14
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
Device Enabled (136):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (138): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (267): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (268):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (269):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (270):    10.000000
Device Product ID (254):    2, 14
Device Node (255):  "/dev/input/event7"
Evdev Axis Inversion (271): 0, 0
Evdev Axis Calibration (272):   <no items>
Evdev Axes Swap (273):  0
Axis Labels (274):  "Abs MT Position X" (294), "Abs MT Position Y" (295), "Abs MT Pressure" (296), "Abs Tool Width" (292), "Abs MT Touch Major" (293), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0)
Button Labels (275):    "Button Left" (139), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Wheel Up" (142), "Button Wheel Down" (143)
Evdev Scrolling Distance (276): 0, 0, 0
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (277):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (278):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (279): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (280): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (281):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (282):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (283):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (284):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (285):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (286):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (287): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (288):  0
```

I don't know what driver is installed, but I've tried to install the synaptics driver and it apt-get tries to uninstall some xorg packages (xorg, xserver-xorg-core-lts-utopic, xserver-xorg-input-evdev-lts-utopic, xserver-xorg-lts-utopic, xserver-xorg-video-intel-lts-utopic, xubuntu-desktop) and installing xserver-xorg-core.

THat makes me think there are some uneven versions of things installed, but even if I accept apt-get's solution, it fails, complaining:

> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
>
> E: Unable to lock the download directory

I don't need to install synaptics if I can just get the touchpad working, but I suspect I will need to. Any ideas?

Comment: Your touchpad is detected and according to xinput should work. It is OK that some "lts-utopic"packages are uninstalled. Try to run `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all`.

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-input-all : Depends: xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: xserver-xorg-input-wacom but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: It looks that upgrade did not run smooth. First try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`.  And what does `cat /etc/lsb-release` show?

Comment: -f shows "0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded."

Comment: cat /etc/lsb-release shows
 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10

DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"

Comment: Some dependencies are broken. It is hard to debug. Generally it is not a good idea to upgrade an lts version to non-lts. The fastest solution will be to re-install 14.04. You can have same kernel and graphics as in 14.04 or 15.04 there. Or install another release.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I had wanted to go straight to 15.04 anyway--I should have just done that! Crossing fingers.

Comment: But I see no reason of installing 15.04. But this is your choice. Fresh install should work OK.

Comment: Do you know that 15.04 is NOT lts?

Comment: Oh! I didn't. Well, fresh install it is then I guess, now to decide in which direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)